# Random Forest: Grid Search Run-time Error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

I am tuning my RandomForestClassifier by using GridSearchCV by sklearn.
I am tuning two parameters only:

"n_estimators" and "min_samples_leaf".

This is the section of the code:

```
RFC=RandomForestClassifier(criterion='entropy', random_state=42, max_features='log2', warm_start=True, oob_score=True, n_jobs=-1)
our_param_grid = [ {'n_estimators':[400, 500, 600, 700]}, {'min_samples_leaf':[50, 70, 90, 110, 130, 150, 170, 190]} ]
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = RFC, param_grid = our_param_grid, cv=3)
grid.fit(X, Y)
print grid.best_params_
```

I am getting warning and an error regarding the OOB_Score.

This is the warning which I am getting.

```
Warning: Some inputs do not have OOB scores. This probably means too few trees where used to compute any reliable oob estimators.                                                                                                                  
warn("Some inputs do not have OOB scores. "
```

And after that an error popped out, resulting in termination of the program. This is the exact error which I am getting.

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide predictions[k].sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis])
{'n_estimators': 700}
```

I have set oob_score=True when making the RFC model. Can anyone please help me understand, where I am going wrong.

Comment: can you upload your X, y data?

Comment: Hi @sera,  My X contains 2lac samples each with 263 features, so it is a matrix of (2lac*263). I have scaled this matrix (mean =0, and standard deviation =1) before fitting it to the RandomForestClassifier. And my "Y" is an array of zero and one values (1 lac zeros and 1 lac ones). I am unable to upload a csv file here at SO. Thankyou for your help.

Comment: Can you check if you have NaNs in your data? This could cause the proble. Also, try to decrease the number of estimators e.g. use 100 and let me know if the Warning persists

Comment: I have already replaced all NaNs values, with the column mean. And I have reduced no of features from 700 to 263 using dimensionality reduction technique (PCA). Actually, this is a malware detection problem, I can not reduce the no of features. And if I am using RandomForestClassifier without GridSearchCV,  passing parameters one by one, then it is working properly. So, I guess it is some problem with GridSearchCV, may be there is some upper limit on the size of data, but nothing is mentioned regarding this in the documentation.

Comment: I posted a possible solution. please let me know

Answer (score 0):

To continue my comment...

Can you use the following and try to run the GridSearchCV ?

```
our_param_grid = {'n_estimators':[400, 500, 600, 700] , 'min_samples_leaf':[50, 70, 90, 110, 130, 150, 170, 190]}
```

Explanation:

I think this is the problem since the GridSearchCV expects `param_grid` to be a dictionary.

In your case you have a list and it seems that after `n_estimator = 700`, it stucks and cannot 'see' the `min_samples_leaf`.